# Fwrite solution rewrite PHP

Tags: php, post, fopen, fwrite

So.. i have problems with this code :

```
$filename = "info.txt"; 
$tex = $_POST['Name']; 
$text = $tex . $_POST['Surname']; 
$fp = fopen ($filename, "w"); 
if ($fp) { 
fwrite ($fp, $text); 
fclose ($fp);
```

It saves ONLY 1 name & surname. after another person submits his info, previous information is lost.

Is it possible to save all information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the mode for fopen :

change 'w' to 'a' (*a* for *append*)

You'll find more information about each mode right here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters

Comment: and.. it writes like :  JohnDoeDojnSmith (in one line)
Can I writes this 2 names in another lines? @matthew

Comment: @user3043737 to have a newline you have to write the "\n" character

Comment: fwrite ($fp, $text . "\n");